# String length causes access violation values -Visual Studio C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, pointers, memory-management

Before I talk about the problem, let me explain what did not work:

1) Tried to not return any value and made the function `void`
2) Made lots of changes in pointers tried `array[i]`, `*(array+i)`
The only way I will not get the error would be when storage to the `string` variable is changed onto simple `cout<<`. The error appears when the `i=25` or in other words when the `array[]` is longer than 25.

```
string kelime_uret(int dizi[], int length) {
    string kelime;
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {

        if (dizi[i] == 1) { kelime[i] = 'A'; }
        else if (dizi[i] == 2) { kelime[i] = 'B'; }
        else if (dizi[i] == 3) { kelime[i] = 'C'; }
        else if (dizi[i] == 4) { kelime[i] = char(128); }
        else if (dizi[i] == 5) { kelime[i] = 'D'; }
        else if (dizi[i] == 6) { kelime[i] = 'E'; }
        else if (dizi[i] == 7) { kelime[i] = 'F'; }
        else if (dizi[i] == 8) { kelime[i] = 'G'; }
        else if (dizi[i] == 9) { kelime[i] = char(166); }
        else if (dizi[i] == 10) { kelime[i] = 'H'; }
        else if (dizi[i] == 11) { kelime[i] = 'I'; }
        else if (dizi[i] == 12) { kelime[i] = char(152); }
        else if (dizi[i] == 13) { kelime[i] = 'J'; }
        else if (dizi[i] == 14) { kelime[i] = 'K'; }
        else if (dizi[i] == 15) { kelime[i] = 'L'; }
        else if (dizi[i] == 16) { kelime[i] = 'M'; }
        else if (dizi[i] == 17) { kelime[i] = 'N'; }
        else if (dizi[i] == 18) { kelime[i] = 'O'; }
        else if (dizi[i] == 19) { kelime[i] = char(153); }
        else if (dizi[i] == 20) { kelime[i] = 'P'; }
        else if (dizi[i] == 21) { kelime[i] = 'R'; }
        else if (dizi[i] == 22) { kelime[i] = 'S'; }
        else if (dizi[i] == 23) { kelime[i] = char(158); }
        else if (dizi[i] == 24) { kelime[i] = 'T'; }
        else if (dizi[i] == 25) { kelime[i] = 'U'; }
        else if (dizi[i] == 26) { kelime[i] = char(154); }
        else if (dizi[i] == 27) { kelime[i] = 'V'; }
        else if (dizi[i] == 28) { kelime[i] = 'Y'; }
        else if (dizi[i] == 29) { kelime[i] = 'Z'; }
        else if (dizi[i] == 30) { kelime[i] = ' '; }
        else if (dizi[i] == 31) { kelime[i] = ','; }
        else if (dizi[i] == 32) { kelime[i] = '.'; }
        else if (dizi[i] == 33) { kelime[i] = '!'; }
        else if (dizi[i] == 34) { kelime[i] = '?'; }
        else if (dizi[i] == 35) { kelime[i] = '-'; }
        else if (dizi[i] == 36) { kelime[i] = ';'; }
        else if (dizi[i] == 37) { kelime[i] = ':'; }
        else if (dizi[i] == 38) { kelime[i] = '1'; }
        else if (dizi[i] == 39) { kelime[i] = '2'; }
        else if (dizi[i] == 40) { kelime[i] = '3'; }
        else if (dizi[i] == 41) { kelime[i] = '4'; }
        else if (dizi[i] == 42) { kelime[i] = '5'; }
        else if (dizi[i] == 43) { kelime[i] = '6'; }
        else if (dizi[i] == 44) { kelime[i] = '7'; }
        else if (dizi[i] == 45) { kelime[i] = '8'; }
        else if (dizi[i] == 46) { kelime[i] = '9'; }
        else if (dizi[i] == 47) { kelime[i] = '0'; }
        else cout << "ERROR" << endl;
    }//i value 25 error dizi[i] 42 >>>> 0x00007FF7B02B150E noktasında, Affin.exe üzerinde özel durum oluştu: 0xC0000005: 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF konumuna okuma erişimi ihlali.

    return kelime;
}
```

This is how I make a call:

```
cout << kelime_uret(dizi, encrypted.size());
```

**P.S. 

dizi -> array,
 
kelime -> word**
The number of array's set members is the same as the number of characters in `encrypted`.

Comment: And what is the magic relationship between `dizi` and `encrypted` so we know how big the array really is?

Comment: @John3136 they are both exactly with the same length. `encrypted` has letters and `dizi` consists of numbers only. A number of numbers in `dizi` is the same as a number of `char`'s in the encrypted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not allocating any memory for `kelime` before accessing `kelime[i]`.

Add a call to `kelime.resize()` before entering the loop (and the loop itself can be greatly simplified), eg:

```
static const char letters[] = "ABC\x80""DEFG\xA6HI\x98JKLMNO\x99PRS\x9ETU\x9AVYZ ,.!?-;:1234567890";

string kelime_uret(int dizi[], int length)
{
    string kelime;
    int value;

    kelime.resize(length);

    for (int i = 0; i < length; ++i)
    {
        value = dizi[i];
        if ((value >= 1) && (value <= 47)) {
            kelime[i] = letters[value-1];
        }
        else {
            cout << "ERROR" << endl;
        }
    }

    return kelime;
}
```

Or, you can omit `resize()` (but do consider using `reserve()` at least), and then use `kelime.push_back(...)` or `kelime += ...` instead of `kelime[i]`, eg:

```
static const char letters[] = "ABC\x80""DEFG\xA6HI\x98JKLMNO\x99PRS\x9ETU\x9AVYZ ,.!?-;:1234567890";

string kelime_uret(int dizi[], int length)
{
    string kelime;
    int value;

    kelime.reserve(length);

    for (int i = 0; i < length; ++i)
    {
        value = dizi[i];
        if ((value >= 1) && (value <= 47)) {
            kelime += letters[value-1];
        }
        else {
            kelime += '\0';
            cout << "ERROR" << endl;
        }
    }

    return kelime;
}
```

Alternatively, use `std::ostringstream` instead of `std::string`, eg:

```
static const char letters[] = "ABC\x80""DEFG\xA6HI\x98JKLMNO\x99PRS\x9ETU\x9AVYZ ,.!?-;:1234567890";

string kelime_uret(int dizi[], int length)
{
    ostringstream kelime;
    int value;

    for (int i = 0; i < length; ++i)
    {
        value = dizi[i];
        if ((value >= 1) && (value <= 47)) {
            kelime << letters[value-1];
        }
        else {
            kelime << '\0';
            cout << "ERROR" << endl;
        }
    }

    return kelime.str();
}
```

Comment: @GiorgiGvimradze: yes

Answer (score 2):

```
string kelime;
```

makes a size zero `std::string`. This means any

```
kelime[i]
```

will be out of bounds and invoke [Undefined Behaviour](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub). After that, no one knows what will happen in the program.

Either [size the string ahead of time with `std::string::resize`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/resize) if you know the length (looks like you do) or use any of the many methods for adding to a string including: `std::string::push_back`, the += operator, and `std::string::append`. Alternately, switch over to a `std::stringstream`.